# Microsoft Office on Linux? VM route or WINE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, microsoft-office, wine

This past year, I got into Linux and I love it. As of right now, I am running a dual boot system with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I'm still in school so I need to keep the windows for Microsoft Office and Adobe Suites.

Up till now, the dual boot has worked well for my needs, but now I would like to somehow be able to use MS office when I'm using Ubuntu. (The open office and libre office change formatting and layouts and my professors get upset).

I read online and some people say to try the WINE approach, but I hear that is difficult and the install is often erroneous.

I was thinking installing win7 or win10 on a virtual machine and running office on that? Is there any way I can strip down the OS image to conserve resources? Any other ideas?

**Computer Specs**

**Processor:** i7-4510U @2.00Ghz, 2601Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 logical processor(s)

**RAM:** 8 gb ddr3

**Unallocated Disk Space:** 50 GB which I'm willing to partition up for the VM

Thanks,
ex080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a VM is probably a better way to go. It's more resource intensive, but more reliable and stable then WINE. It looks like you have the resources available to do this.

Comment: This was most helpful, as this is what I ended up doing. I stripped down a windows 7 install and gave the vm 1 core and 2 gb ram. It works fantastically. I also disabled windows services that were not essential to MS office

Answer (score 2):

*Late Post*

I tried both. VM is the definitely the way to go.

I installed  office 2013 using Wine. The task was difficult in itself.
At the beginning,  MS Word seemed to work well. But, when I tried to add an equation, it threw error. It happened with lot of other things. Similar with Excel. Using Office on wine demands  lot of  work; still it won't work fully well.

Next, I used virtualbox and installed office 2016 on Windows 7 allocating 2 GB RAM. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

VM's are great for testing software and for playing around, but for day-to-day work it gets to be a bit inconvenient.  I have no direct experience running MS Office in WINE, but to my knowledge, it works well.  If you're willing to spend some extra money, there's a paid product called Crossover Office (from Codeweavers) that is supposed to make the configuration easier.  I have no experience with that either, but it might be worth checking out.  I see that they have a trial version available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using Linux command line applications (i.e. no GUI) I would suggest going the other way around: install [Ubuntu on Windows 10 instead](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)

You would get a true Ubuntu userspace, and access to the documents you have on Windows. Speed-wise, is definitively faster than emulation, and it is relatively easier to install.

That being said, if you need a GUI application on Linux, this *works*, but not nearly as well as I would like it before endorsing it.